# How to store JSON result iteratively from POST method in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using requests to call a web-service that responds with a JSON.  The problem is that this JSON has paging enabled, which basically means I can return 100 records tops per time the service is called.  When I call the server, I might receive 100, then 100, then 23, then the loop closes, but the only records that I would have stored in my variables are the last 23.  The parameter in the JSON below which increases to return a new set of records is StartRowNum.  This starts at 0 and increases based on how many loops the program runs, i.e. if there are 200 records, the StartRowNum to retrieve the last 100 would be 101, if there are 300 records it would be 201, and so on.
How would I store the first and second 100?

```
    f2 =open('C:\Users\GeoffreyWest\Desktop\Request.json')
    data2 = jsonpickle.decode((f2.read()))
    data2 = jsonpickle.encode(data2)
    lastpage = 'false'
    startrow = 0
    newquery = 'new'
    pagesize = 100
    url2 = "URL"
    headers2 = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

    while lastpage == 'false':
    r2 = requests.post(url2, data=data2, headers=headers2)
    print r2.text
    decoded2 = json.loads(r2.text)
    f2 =open('C:\Users\GeoffreyWest\Desktop\Request.json')
    data2 = jsonpickle.decode((f2.read()))
    if decoded2['Response']['LastPage'] == 'false':
        data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize'] = pagesize
        startrow = startrow + data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize']
        data2['QueryRequest']['StartRowNum'] = startrow
        data2['QueryRequest']['NewQuery'] = 'false'
        data2 = jsonpickle.encode(data2)
        print startrow
    else:
        lastpage = 'true'
```

Example of JSON that is sent to server:

```
{
    "MetaData": {},
    "QueryRequest": {
        "LastUpdatedDate": "06/29/2015 23:00:00",
        "srType": [
            "Bulky Items",
            "Electronic Waste",
            "Metal/Household Appliances",
            "Dead Animal Removal",
            "Service Not Complete",
            "Manual Pickup",
            "Brush Items Pickup",
            "Move In/Move Out",
            "Containers",
            "Illegal Dumping Pickup"
        ],
        "NewQuery": "new", 
        "PageSize": "100",
        "StartRowNum": "0"

    }
}
```

Comment: Well why are you *replacing* `data2`?!

Comment: Not quite sure at what you're getting at..